# How do I know what spring size should be installed on my garage door

Tags: garage

My springs were replaced about 9 months ago with the same size that was already there - 207x28

I needed an unrelated repair but the first thing this guy said was that the springs were not the right size, as it was too difficult to manually open the garage door. He recommended 218. He said if I continue to use these springs my motor will likely blow.

The original company says what the installed is fine but they will replace if I want them to.

I don't know what to do...

Comment: If the door and the springs are adjusted property, then the door should be easy to lift by hand.  Garage door springs can be adjusted, but they are powerful and one job that should be left to the professionals(they can kill/maim).  The spring size depends on the weight of the door installed, so the right size spring for the door.

Comment: Why not consult the company that replaced the springs about the new repair.  It is usually not a good idea to inset new characters into the play.

Comment: We have a home warranty, so they assign the vendor. I did try to lift the garage door by hand and it was not easy. The second person said it should be liftable with one finger. He did get out his scale, release all the weight on the scale and show me the matrix for the appropriate size. But there was a bit of a language barrier and I don't really know anything about garage doors. I'm at the mercy of the professionals. @RMDman - I did speak with the original co. who said the springs are fine but offered to replace when I pushed

Comment: Perhaps get a third opinion.

Comment: The vender that said the door should be able to be lifted with one finger was exaggerating  a bit.  The normal thought is operable with one hand, or arm.  It is likely that the springs need to be adjusted or changed to give the door more assist.

Comment: Are the spring spiral around a rod above the door, or along the sides of the door?  The spiral springs can be adjusted for more assist.  That must be done by a professional because it is dangerous.

Comment: it is based on garage door weight

Comment: They are above the door